# how to parse a particular output like in rows as the output comes in a clubbed way in python?

Tags: python, matching

When I run the code below, the output comes as such. I need the output to show in rows **and** only the values under the  caption.

Desired output:

```
caption : 3PAR
          3PAR
```

Actual output:

```
('Caption                          DeviceID             Model                            Partitions  Size         \r\r\n3PARdata VV SCSI Disk Device     \\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE19  3PARdata VV SCSI Disk Device     0           1069286400   \r\r\nHP P2000 G3 FC SCSI Disk Device  \\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE1   HP P2000 G3 FC SCSI Disk Device  1           49993251840  \r\r\nHP HSV360 SCSI Disk Device       \\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE7   HP HSV360 SCSI Disk Device       4           1069286400   \r\r\nHP HSV360 SCSI Disk Device       \\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE27  HP HSV360 SCSI Disk Device       0           1069286400   \r\r\nHP HSV360 SCSI Disk Device       \\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE5   HP HSV360 SCSI Disk Device       0           1069286400   \r\r\nHP P2000 G3 FC SCSI Disk Device  \\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE23  HP P2000 G3 FC SCSI Disk Device  1           49993251840  \r\r\n3PARdata VV SCSI Disk Device     \\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE13  3PARdata
```

Code:

```
p5=subprocess.Popen("rsh -l Administrator 10.10.11.37 \"wmic diskdrive list brief\"",stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)


result = p5.communicate()
status = p5.wait()
print(result),
```

Comment: As you do not know exacty what part you want, and how you want to split it : **why** and **how** `3PAR` instead of `3PARdata` of `3PARdata VV SCSI Disk Device`, my better answer is just `print ('3PAR')` or `print ('caption : 3PAR\n          3PAR')` !

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the values under `Caption` then use `re` to split on the space after `Disk Device` which is common in all Caption  rows:

```
result = """Caption                          DeviceID             Model                            Partitions  Size         \r\r\n3PARdata VV SCSI Disk Device     \\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE19  3PARdata VV SCSI Disk Device     0           1069286400   \r\r\nHP P2000 G3 FC SCSI Disk Device  \\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE1   HP P2000 G3 FC SCSI Disk Device  1           49993251840  \r\r\nHP HSV360 SCSI Disk Device       \\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE7   HP HSV360 SCSI Disk Device       4           1069286400   \r\r\nHP HSV360 SCSI Disk Device       \\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE27  HP HSV360 SCSI Disk Device       0           1069286400   \r\r\nHP HSV360 SCSI Disk Device       \\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE5   HP HSV360 SCSI Disk Device       0           1069286400   \r\r\nHP P2000 G3 FC SCSI Disk Device  \\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE23  HP P2000 G3 FC SCSI Disk Device  1           49993251840  \r\r\n3PARdata VV SCSI Disk Device     \\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE13  3PARdata"""
import re
spl = result.splitlines()
print(spl[0].split()[0].rstrip())
for line in spl[1:]:
    if line:
        print(re.split("(?<=Disk Device)\s+",line,1)[0])

Caption
3PARdata VV SCSI Disk Device
HP P2000 G3 FC SCSI Disk Device
HP HSV360 SCSI Disk Device
HP HSV360 SCSI Disk Device
HP HSV360 SCSI Disk Device
HP P2000 G3 FC SCSI Disk Device
3PARdata VV SCSI Disk Device
```

Comment: The above code is working fine if we hard code the output to a variable,instead of hard coding or assigning the output in "result" as keeps on changing for each server output as it is based upon command output , Can the output be split in the required format as per command result      
HP P2000 G3 FC SCSI Disk Device
HP HSV360 SCSI Disk Device
HP HSV360 SCSI Disk Device
HP HSV360 SCSI Disk Device
HP P2000 G3 FC SCSI Disk Device
3PARdata VV SCSI Disk Device

Comment: @suman, not sure what you mean, result is just the output from running the command, `p5.communicate()[0]` will be exactly the same as result above. Also you should really use `check_output` and pass a list of args

Comment: @Padriac after adding "check_output" problem is resolved thanks for the suggestion..it helped a lots